# Implementing indexing "operator" in on a class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

How would one go about implementing the indexing "operator" on a class in C# ?

```
class Foo {

}

Foo f = new Foo();
f["key"] = "some val";
f["other key"] = "some other val";
```

in C# ? Searched MSDN but came up empty.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is an example using a dictionary as storage:

```
public class Foo {

    private Dictionary<string, string> _items;

    public Foo() {
        _items = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public string this[string key] {
        get {
            return _items[key];
        }
        set {
            _items[key]=value;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    private List<string> MyList = new List<string>();
    public string this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return MyList[i];
        }
        set
        {
            MyList[i] = value;
        }

    }
```

You can define several accessors for different types (ie string instead of int for example) if it's needed.

Answer (score 5):

There called Indexers or sometimes Indexer Properties.

Here's the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) page about them.

Comment: ah, so that's the name - hate when you know what you want and how it should work, and you know it's possible because you seen it + done it a whole lot of other languages ... you just don't know the name of it on this platform.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean. That's why I thought I'd submit this answer although others had already given the syntax. Glad it helped.