# Implementing indexing in C# property

Tags: c#, indexing

For what i have been reading, with another Class I would be able to add the indexing to the property. But i am not managing to achieve the get/set of the "Option[x]" property of my custom "Poll" class.

```
public class Poll
{
    //Constructor
    public Poll() { }
    //Properties
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }
    public Options Option { get; set; }
    private string title;
}
public class Options
{
    string[] option = { };
    public string this[int i]
    {
        get { return option[i]; }
        set { option[i] = value; }
    }
}
```

When i try to add the first option to the poll, it says the object ("Options") has not being instantiated. And it does make sense. But I couldn't figure out where in Poll i would instantiate it.

So, can anyone explain me what am i doing wrong? Am i following the right direction? Or point to me further reading. For the solutions I have seen, this one seemed the most logical to me, but was only a small raw example, low on details.

I didn't want to follow the dictionary ([Implementing indexing "operator" in on a class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623401/implementing-indexing-operator-in-on-a-class-in-c-sharp)) way, or "Option" property returning a List of strings.

Comment: Your constructor should initialize the property.

Comment: Even if you do set `Option` to an instance of `Options`, the indexer will always throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` because the `option` array is always an empty array.

Comment: `public Poll() { Option = new Options()}`

Comment: Thank you for your quick and concise answers. All three comments are correct. The problem is solved. What should i do with this question now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
public Poll() { }
```

To:

```
public Poll() { Option = new Options(); }
```

Also pay attention to "Wai Ha Lee" pointed out: *"the indexer will always throw an IndexOutOfRangeException because the option array is always an empty array."*

What he means is that you have to replace:

```
string[] option = { };
```

With:

```
string[] option = new string[X]; //X is Array size
```